# Cost of a thread hanging on a lock

Tags: java, android, multithreading, locking

Scenario:

- one thread is polling for a certain event when app is in the foreground
- second thread wants to call a method `fun()` once that first thread 
  notifies the second thread using event bus about that certain event
- second thread holds a lock until it is notified by that first thread
- app is backgrounded but second thread still holds that lock

Question:
what are the hidden costs of holding the lock on the second threads? Is there something to worry about?

Comment: AFAIK, As it is waiting for the signal and not checking for it permanently, the cost should be negligible (in front of the memory your background app uses)

Comment: The thing to worry about is deadlocking. If  thread 1 needs access to the resource locked by thread 2, the program can never proceed (thus the name of deadlock). I think that's the main thing to keep in mind when using locks.

Comment: @pskink I would think that the OP means the "natural" lock you obtain when using the keyword  `synchronized` or a synchronized block

Comment: @psink The second thread does not have Looper. It's locked using RxJava's toBlocking coming from BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 1):

From a general standpoint, you always want to avoid deadlock scenarios. Make sure there is always a way for the second thread to drop the lock.

Take a look here for a good example of deadlock. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html